# PHP cannot find COM class that is enabled in phpinfo

Tags: php, laravel, com

Trying to use the COM class to run a process in the background. Laravel is throwing an error that the COM class is not found.

Im using Laravel and PHP 5.5 (x86 NTS) on Windows Server 2008 R2.

In my php.ini I have uncommented out the line:

```
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
```

Restarted the server... (IISReset /stop, IISReset /start)

PHPInfo() is showing:

```
com_dotnet
COM support => enabled
```

I've ensured there is no other dll on my server with this name. I've replaced it with a fresh copy in case the dll is corrupted.

Any ideas what I'm missing? Do I need to tell Laravel how to use this class through composer or something?

**Update:**

Can call COM class from a basic PHP file - just not from Laravel - Not sure how to add to Laravel - any ideas?

Comment: Are you inserting `use COM;` at the top of your controllers / wherever you're utilizing it in Laravel?

Comment: You are so right. That was the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Great, glad you got it working! No problem :).

Comment: You can also use `\COM` in your code, instead of `use COM;`. I'd recommend taking a quick look at [PHP namespacing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php), just so you have a full grasp on the concept!